# How do I find the categorical name corresponding to the encoded values ​after fit_transform() in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I'm doing label encoding with `LabelEncoder()`. I want to know what is the categorical name corresponding to the encoded values. For example:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = LabelEncoder()
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df['Name']= le.fit_transform(df['Name'])
df
```

When i use this, code works successfully. But how do i know encoded `tom=2` or `nick=1`? This is a really big problem when working with big data. How do i save these encoded categorical informations?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`LabelEncoder.inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.inverse_transform)

```
le.inverse_transform([1])
array(['nick'], dtype=object)
```